# How to replace all occurrences of matching string in a database table using ColdFusion

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion

Working with a MS Access database, using one particular table, and scattered throughout the table at varying positions in date columns (which themselves can be in varying orders as a result of the data import) is the text "Not known". I want to replace occurrences of that text string across the whole data table.

The only way I can think of doing it is export to a csv format, and do a REReplace then import the data again, but I would like to know if there is a 'slicker' way?

The columns contain data which is a data import from a csv file so all the columns are text,  they can contain a mix of "date string", text, numbers (as string) and null.

Comment: Do you have text in a date column? Does Access allow this?

Comment: Its a data import from a csv file so all the columns are text, so they can contain a mix of "date string" and text and null.

Comment: @Saul - Do you really *need* a regex replace? If not, most db's have a sql replace() function ie `UPDATE tableName SET col1 = replace(...), col2 = replace(...)`. (Though the code should really validate *before* inserting. Then you could use proper date columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace, it follows basic TSQL implementation :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Here is an example I did updating the customers table of the Northwind sample database:

```
update customers set Customers.[Job Title] = replace( Customers.[Job Title], 'Purchasing', 'Manufacturing');
```

So to distill it into a generic example :

```
update TABLENAME set FIELD = 
    replace( FIELD, 'STRING_TO_REPLACE', 'STRING_TO_REPLACE_WITH' )
```

That updates the entire table in one statement.  Be careful   ;)

Comment: The replace function works fine in Access and runs in the SQL design window, but as not via Coldfusion SQL statement which is I think ODBC

Comment: If this is a once-off script, executing it in access shouldn't be a problem.  However, if it is, loop the query and do it row by row.  Doing it once to scrub your data isn't a performance issue imo.  Future updates to the data can be scrubbed before update.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Access, running edit-replace command. If you need to do this in code - you can open recordset, loop through records and for each field run:

```
rst.fields(i)=replace(rst.fields(i),"Not known","Something")
```

this is how it works in VBA, beleive you can do something similar in coldfusion

Comment: The Replace() function is available only from within Access, not via ODBC or OLEDB. But it's also not very sensible to do it line-by-line with a recordset, when you could do a SQL UPDATE batch command.

Comment: I don't work except in Access, so I'd use a SQL UPDATE with the Replace() function. From outside Access, you'd have to write nested functions using Len() and Mid() and Left() to do the same as the Replace().

Comment: The replace function works fine in Access, but as David says not via Coldfusion SQL statement which is I think ODBC

Answer (score 0):

Why not just open the CSV file in Notepad++ (or similar) and do a Find/Replace?